# express-flash-messages not working within promise function

Tags: node.js, express

i am using express-flash-messages package in express js to display messages on the page, all is going good but inside of promise function in the code, the req.flash doesn't set a value in the session, could any one please suggest whats wrong?

main.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('express-flash-messages')
var app = express();


app.use(session({
key: 'user_id',
secret: 'testcookie',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: false,
cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2
    },
}))


app.use(flash());
```

routes/index.js

```
    (async () => {

        var promise = users_model.create({fullname: req.body.inputFullName, email_id: req.body.inputEmailId, mob_number: req.body.inputContactNumber, dateandtime: now})

        promise.then(() => {

            console.log('Record Inserted successfully!!');

            req.flash('success', 'Form Submitted!'); // not getting set


        }).catch((err) => {

            req.flash('error', 'An error occured, Please try again.'); // not getting set

        })


    })()


    req.flash('success', 'Form Submitted!');  // works here
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return or await the promise:

```
 (async () => {

        var promise = users_model.create({fullname: req.body.inputFullName, email_id: req.body.inputEmailId, mob_number: req.body.inputContactNumber, dateandtime: now})

        // or return instead of await 
        await promise.then(() => {

            console.log('Record Inserted successfully!!');

            req.flash('success', 'Form Submitted!'); // not getting set


        }).catch((err) => {

            req.flash('error', 'An error occured, Please try again.'); // not getting set

        })


    })()
```

Comment: oh thats right, forgot somehow. thanks for the suggestion